# Unable to allocate array with shape (35126, 224, 224, 3) and data type float32

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I'm making a Diabetic Retinopathy Detection by using machine learning in python.

I have a 35126 image in training data an I want to let them into array but I have a problem to allocate array with shape (35126, 224, 224, 3) it show

MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (35126, 224, 224, 3) and data type float32

I have a 16GB Ram

This is my code using keras

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
import glob
import pywt
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from skimage import exposure
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
train_image = []
df_train = pd.read_csv('trainlabel/trainLabels.csv')
y = df_train['level']
score_svm = []
score_rf = []


def getscore(model,x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    return model.score(x_test,y_test)
#tqdm(range(df_train.shape[0]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 16))
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
for i in tqdm(range(df_train.shape[0])) :
    img = image.load_img('train/'+'trainimage/'+'train/'+df_train['image'][i]+'.jpeg',target_size=(256,256,3))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img / 255
    print(type(img))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = exposure.equalize_hist(img)
    img_adpeq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(img,clip_limit=0.03)
    print(type(img_adpeq))
    train_image.append(img_adpeq)
    print(type(train_image))

X = np.asarray(train_image)
print(type(X))
nsamples, nx, ny = X.shape
X2 =X.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
print(X2.shape)
kf = KFold(n_splits=5)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index],X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    nsamples, nx, ny = X_train.shape
    X_train = X_train.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
    nsamples, nx, ny = X_test.shape
    X_test = X_test.reshape((nsamples, nx * ny))
    score_svm.append(getscore(SVC(),X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test))
    score_rf.append(getscore(RandomForestClassifier(),X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test))

print("SVM")
print(score_svm)
print("Random Forest")
print(score_rf)
```

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (35126, 254, 256, 3) and data type float32

it's my first time ,so it seem like a dirty code sorry.

Comment: your batch size is too large (use e.g. 64?), and to allocate your array, you would need roughly 20 GB of RAM (multiply all numbers, and for float32 you take this number times 4, and then work your way back to GB).

Comment: I edit a code to my first algorithm because I confuse between machine learning and deep learning but it show a same problem too